# Как показывать Activity в TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragment, tab

Я новичок в андроид . У меня есть программа интернет магазин в которой я хочу реализовать TabLayout, на данный момент активность переключается через.

Fragment :

```
public class ActivityHome extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
GridView gridview;
AdapaterGridView gridviewAdapter;
ArrayList<GridViewItem> data = new ArrayList<GridViewItem>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    data.add(new 
    GridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_product), 
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_product)));
    data.add(new 
    GridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_product2), 
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_product2)));
    data.add(new 
    GridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_product3), 
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_product3)));
    data.add(new 
    GridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_profile), 
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_profile)));
```

Это моя активность которую я хочу реализовать в TabLayout :

```
public class ActivityCategoryList1 extends Activity {
GridView listCategory1;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
TextView txtAlert;
// объявить объект адаптера для создания пользовательского списка категорий
AdapterCategoryList1 cla1;
// создавать переменные arraylist для хранения данных с сервера
static ArrayList<Long> Category1_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category1_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category1_image = new ArrayList<String>();
String Category1API;
int IOConnect = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category1_list);

    prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    listCategory1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listCategory1);
    txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);
    cla1 = new AdapterCategoryList1(ActivityCategoryList1.this);
    // category API url
    Category1API = Constant.Category1API+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey+"&category1_id=";
    // вызов класса асинтетики для запроса данных с сервера
    new getDataTask().execute();
    // прослушиватель событий для обработки списка при нажатии
    listCategory1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // перейти к странице меню
            Intent iActivityCategoryList = new Intent(ActivityCategoryList1.this, ActivityCategoryList.class);
            iActivityCategoryList.putExtra("category_id", Category1_ID.get(position));
            startActivity(iActivityCategoryList);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
        }});}
```

Помогите кто знает как это сделать.

Comment: Если вопрос звучит : как добавить активити во вкладку в TabLayout? Ответ - никак. Перенесите всю логику с активити в фрагмент, а его можно будет прикрепить

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Значит получается то что в фрагменте не реализуемо показ активности целиком...

Comment: можно "показать" фрагмент в активити, но наоборот нельзя никак. активити  "вершина" иерархии отображемых на экране классов